# Publish asp.net core 1.0 RTM as source files

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, asp.net-core

I remember that in the RC1 of asp.net core, the project was published with the sourcefiles, unless you checked the option 'Compile as NuGet packages' or something. This option is gone and all the publishing actions Compile to Dll files by default.

Is there a new option in asp.net core 1.0.1 RTM(or 1.1.0 preview) to publish a project as .cs files, so they are editable as in the RC1 version without compiling the code again?

Comment: Microsoft makes it clear that anything can change till RTM. If you do want some feature, ask Microsoft by posting to the correct GitHub repo.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it can change, and rhats what I say in my question. Though, what I am asking is, did I miss something in the release notes that replaces the checkbox, is there a new way to publish as source files in RTM? Or is it just gone/not possible anymore?

Comment: I could not recall whether what you asked existed in RC1 as a "publish option". Microsoft makes it clearly a developer feature, https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/dotnet-watch.html and should be used only at developer machine during development.